# 2.8 smart UV-Project does not work as expected

Tags: uv

Hi on the right side I have selected 4 connected faces and (normals are right and there are no vertices on top of each other) 
then I select smart UV Project. The Result is quite unusual. Two of the faces are placed left and the other two are on the right side.
I would expect them in a row without any gaps.
Is this a bug, am I doing anything wrong?

[image]

Comment: Try to use 'follow active quad' in this case

Comment: you will also get better results if you mark your seams before unwrapping (Edit mode, top menu: "Edges" --> "Mark Seams").